# authlogic connect tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, authlogic

I am trying to add the facebook connect to an existing site in rails 3 that uses authlogic.
so that  existing users can sign in via their facebook account (I'll find existing account via email id in facebook ) and new users can sign up using facebook too.

I am trying to use authlogic connect
( I found other alternative like omniauth , facebooker2 etc , omniauth plays well with devise but I dont want to move to devise & it seems only authlogic connect plays well with authlogic and rails3 )

But I am unable to find some proper tutorial where I could understand how to use it.

I looked at their project site :

https://github.com/viatropos/authlogic-connect

I used the little help on their site and tried to do a little.
Now when the facebook login button is clicked it goes to facebook page asks for all the permission and then it comes back to a url with code as a paramater. what do I do with the code param ?

Can someone suggest me a proper tutorial (not example) for using the authlogic connect

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really gave up on authlogic connect.
Though it seems its the best solution, It integrates so much iwht the authlogic that I am unable to customize it.

I finally got omniauth working with authlogic , though a lot of things were manually done

railcasts simple omniauth authentication helped a lot,